# How do I extract Unicode normalization tables from the XML Unicode Character Database?

Tags: unicode, unicode-normalization

I'm writing a script to create tables containing unicode characters for case folding, etc.

I was able to extract those tables just fine, but I'm struggling to figure out which properties to use to get codepoints for normalization.

In Unicode Annex #44 the closest property group I can find is the NF(C|D|KC|KD)_QC which is for telling if a string has already been normalized.

and it still doesn't list the values I need to actually build the tables.

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: I'm writing a C library to handle unicode, this isn't a simple one and done, write it in python problem, I'm trying to write my own normalization (technically composition/decomposition) functions.

Edit2: The decomposition property is "dm", but what about composition, and the Kompatibility variants?

Comment: and the unicode standard (in one of the first chapters) you have the rules and algorithm for normalization (and how to handle "future" characters)

Answer (score 2):

The Unicode XML database in the `ucdxml` directory is *not authoritative*. I'd suggest to work with the authoritative files in the `ucd` directory. You'll need

- the fields [Decomposition_Type and Decomposition_Mapping](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-20.html#Decomposition_Type) from column 5 of [UnicodeData.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt),
- the field [Canonical_Combining_Class](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-20.html#Canonical_Combining_Class) from column 3, and
- the composition exclusions from [CompositionExclusions.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/CompositionExclusions.txt).

If there's a decomposition type in angle brackets, it's a compatibility mapping (NFKD), otherwise it's a canonical mapping. Composition is defined in terms of decomposition mappings. See [section 3.11 Normalization Forms](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch03.pdf) of the Unicode standard and [UAX #15](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) for details.